# How is the president of the United Federation of Planets elected?

Tags: star-trek, federation, government

I'm really asking about the pre-Burn Federation, but post-Burn is fine, too. Is the president of the UFP elected by popular vote or some other method? Can the president be from any member planet?

Comment: These seem like 2 separate (but equally valid) questions. I'd make a separate question post here for `Can the president of the UFP be from any member planet?`

Comment: Much like the president of the USA is elected. Everyone votes, then several weeks go by and a panel of judges decide who won.

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/President_of_the_United_Federation_of_Planets#Apocrypha - *"The method of electing the President of the United Federation of Planets has never been discussed in Star Trek canon.*"

Comment: In DS9, "Paradise Lost/Homefront", then president Jaresh-Inyo, mentions that he was content to just be a representative for his world before becoming President.

Comment: How is the President of the United Federation of Planets elected? Very well, thank you.